# Is Chrome still supporting SPDY?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, spdy

I read Chrome dropped SPDY support in 2016: https://blog.chromium.org/2016/02/transitioning-from-spdy-to-http2.html

However some requests in devtools still show SPDY as the protocol:

[image]

Is it really SPDY or it's devtool's display issue? If it's the latter then what's the actual protocol?

Comment: Perhaps your Chrome version is < 51?

Comment: See https://crbug.com/587469 and https://crbug.com/704146

Comment: Seeing the same result in Chrome 68, Edge does show protocol properly as HTTP/2 so developer tools are misleading

Comment: Spotted a few recently with `chrome://net-internals/#events`

Answer (score 3):

`Protocol` being displayed as `spdy` was a bug in Chrome devtools. It is [fixed in Chrome 71](https://crbug.com/704146#c8) (now in beta).

All the occurrences of `spdy` in earlier versions of Chrome (51-70) actually mean `h2`.